# Binding to a Custom Element in a Template Part in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I've created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFbtJ4?p=preview) to illustrate the problem I'm having.

I'm in the middle of creating a dashboard which at the moment contains four different items. Each of these items I'm creating as Custom Elements then wrapping them in a Custom Element called Widget to give them a frame, title and styling. Here's what that snippet looks like:

```
<widget title="A Widget" icon="fa-question">
  <template replace-part="item-template">
    <child-element text.bind="$parent.$parent.someText"></child-element>
  </template>
</widget>
```

For reference the widget view looks like this:

```
<template>
  <require from="./widget.css!"></require>
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
      <i class="fa ${icon}"></i>
      <h3>${title}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
      <template replaceable part="item-template"></template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the view model is:

```
import {bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
export class WidgetCustomElement {
  @bindable title;
  @bindable icon;
  @bindable show; // This is something I want the child element
                  // to be able to bind to and control but haven't
                  // got there yet!!
}
```

But notice I'm trying to bind data from the ViewModel into the child-element where the child-element looks like this:

```
import {bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
export class ChildElementCustomElement {
  @bindable text;
}
```

and the view:

```
<template>
  <p>The widget passed us : ${text}</p>
</template>
```

The problem is no matter what expression I use (and here I'm currently trying `$parent.$parent.someText`) I can't get the binding to work.

Should this work? I've also tried defining the variable `someText` in the main ViewModel as `@bindable someText' but that throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'some-text' of null
    at BindableProperty.initialize (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.14.4/aurelia-templating.js:2448:33)
    at new BehaviorInstance (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.14.4/aurelia-templating.js:2199:23)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.create (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.14.4/aurelia-templating.js:2821:30)
    at https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.14.4/aurelia-templating.js:3385:27
    at f (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:1415:56)
    at https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:1423:13
    at b.exports (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:453:24)
    at b.(anonymous function) (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:1625:11)
    at Number.f (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:1596:24)
    at q (https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-plunker/v0.4.0/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/client/shim.min.js:1600:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since stumbled across something in the Aurelia document detailing [Template Parts](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#template-parts). In *example.js* a `bind()` method is defined which assigns the `bindingContext` to a local member `this.$parent`.

This means all I have to do is defined the following in the view model for my widget:

```
bind(bindingContext) {
   this.$parent = bindingContext;
}
```

Then the `child-element` is bound with the following:

```
<child-element text.bind="$parent.someText"></child-element>
```

I've forked my original [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqlP0O?p=preview) to demonstrate it working.

Given `repeat-for` provides it's own `$parent` I had mistakenly believed there was one automatically defined here!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are looking for this or not, however, introducing a `@bindable text` property in `WidgetCustomElement` makes this a whole lot easier. I worked on your plunk and introduced a `@bindable wtext;` in `WidgetCustomElement`, used this property to bind `someText` in `app` view like below:

```
<widget title="A Widget" icon="fa-question" wtext.bind="someText">
   <template replace-part="item-template">
        <child-element text.bind="wtext"></child-element>
        <!--<child-element text.bind="$parent.$parent.someText"></child-element>-->
   </template>
</widget>
```

And this works. However as I said I am not sure whether this approach works for you or not. What I have assumed is your widget will mostly contain one single child element and if this assumption is correct then this should work, however in case one-to-many mapping (many child element in single widget), something else is needed.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I forked your plunk to make the changes and here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/PkXysZ?p=preview) to that.

Comment: Thanks for the input @sayan. It's not quite what I want but for a slightly different reason. I'm trying to maintain the widget as something that brings a look and feel but doesn't interfere with any business functionality. In other words I want child-element to skip a generation and bind to a higher context which in my application is a dashboard - the dashboard provides child-element with the context it should display information for. My best thought so far is to use DI to inject a shared service between the dashboard and child-element (dashboard reads & writes whilst child-element only reads)